# How does stumbleupon display other website without forcing users to navigate away from their page?

Tags: web, hosting, stumbleupon

How does a website like stumbleupon display/ allow interaction with other sites without navigating away from the original site? I am wondering about the backend/frontend ways to implement something like this and the legality of displaying other sites in this way. 
Here is an example: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/1l2hy9/:18Y+xBpXB:g+HoG4rI/lifehacker.com/5747213/how-to-hack-your-brain?skyline=true&s=i/

Answer (score 2):

They're called [`<iframe>`s.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

```
<iframe width=500 height=500 src='http://stumbleupon.com'>Your browser cannot display this frame.</iframe>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsp6d/)** | **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)**

[image]